# clang says "cstdlib file not found"

Tags: gcc, g++, clang, include-path

On an almost default install of Ubuntu 11.04 I installed clang.

I am trying to compile this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

g++ can deal with it just fine, but clang++ errors out: **fatal error: 'cstdlib' file not found**

Can someone explain why this happens? and what needs to be done to make this work?
I expected clang++ to be a drop-on replacement for g++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like your clang build is not searching the correct platform include paths. Try checking with

```
clang -v ...
```

where it is looking for headers (and check that your platform include paths are there). You *might* have to add additional include directories (e.g. /usr/include/c++/x.y).

You might want to take a look at the source file [`lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp`](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp), The method `AddDefaultCPlusPlusIncludePaths` does some distribution/gcc-version specific magic (I had to fix it for my own system once).

Comment: Yep, thanks, it seems clang++ is borked in natty.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/clang/+bug/779404